# How to prove mathematical induction formulae in LEAN theorem prover?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

Can anyone help me understand how to write the proof of a simple result that can be easily obtained by induction, for example the formula for the sum of the first `n` natural numbers: `1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2`, using the LEAN theorem prover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proof. You'll need [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib) for it to work.

```
import algebra.big_operators tactic.ring

open finset

example (n : ℕ) : 2 * (range (n + 1)).sum id = n * (n + 1) :=
begin
  induction n with n ih,
  { refl },
  { rw [sum_range_succ, mul_add, ih, id.def, nat.succ_eq_add_one],
    ring }
end
```

`range (n + 1)` is the set of natural numbers less than `n + 1`, i.e. 0 to n.

I used the `finset.sum` function. If `s` is a finset and `f` is a function, then 
`s.sum f` is $\sum_{x \in s} f(x)$.

The `induction` tactic does induction. There are then two cases. The case `n = 0` can be done with `refl` since this is nothing more than a computation.

The inductive step can be done with `rw`. Using a VSCode you can click after each comma in my proof to see what each `rw` does. This gets it into a form that the `ring` tactic will solve.

Comment: I think it was "I used"

Comment: Christopher, may I ask for a bit more help? I got stuck with something that looks very simple: `theorem T ( a b : ℕ) (h1: a = 2) (h2: b = 3) : a < b := `. Can't get this to work at all; even though I get `2 < 3`, using `nat.succ` I don't seem to be able to change that to the required type `a<b`. Gave up after some two hours...

Comment: If you `import tactic.norm_num` then `by norm_num` will prove this. `dec_trivial` also works, as does `nat.lt_succ_self _`. `norm_num` is the recommended method as this should have the best performance for large numbers.

Comment: If I do this: `theorem TT ( a b : ℕ) (h1: a = 2) (h2: b = 3) : a < b := begin exact nat.lt_succ_self a end` I get `a < succ a` but expected to have `a<b`. This is what I can't get past. Why doesn't it see that `b=succ a` here? I did do it with `linarith` and `lt_add_one` but it bothers me that I can't figure out what I'm missing in the other approach.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question properly. You should `rw [h1, h2] ` first.